# Calculating dark energy

Tags: entropy

How can entropy or indeed other base 10 mathematical models calculate spacetime, reality & dark Entergy when they have a base 12 mathematical construct?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What is "10 mathematical"? Is that base 10 maths? And what does "entropy...models calculate spacetime..." mean? Please clarify your question as it is currently incoherent.

Comment: Our reality is base 12 mathematically based , Robert Edward Grant with vortex math understands this , in any case dark energy has an evident base 12 duodecimal construct so why pursue an answer with decimal ,you will have heard of the universal constant 3 ,6 9 im.surre

Comment: As far as I can tell the person you mentioned is not a scientist so I don't see any reason to trust their claims. Furthermore, they do not have any papers that I could read to try to understand their claims. Secondly, to my knowledge, it does not matter which base of math you use. We use base 10 daily cause it's easy, computers use base 2 and so on. The laws of Physics, to my knowledge, do not care about the mathematical basis. Finally, your comment does not make sense. "vortex maths" and "duodecimal" are terms that I have never seen in Physics.  I will not argue with you. Have a good one.

Comment: It's time to start counting in duodecimal

Comment: Again, see the answer below. The laws of physics do not care about the math base. So why not use base 60 as we do with clocks? Why is base 12 special? It isn't. Anyways I will stop responding to you now.

Comment: Only man is arrogant enough to think he is the ultimate knowledgebase on this planet of course  it matters what base you do calculations in, as dark energy has a base 12 mathematical construct, good day

Answer (score 5):

Theories and models in physics do not have a preferred mathematical base. The physical constants and properties of substances in a model can be written out in any base - in the same way as constants and properties can be measured in any units, and the model can be described in any language. It is just a question of translation.